# The database created in CPanel does not show in phpmyadmin. Any ideas?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

The problem workflow:

```
1 - Open CPanel on your web browser, 
2 - Login to CPanel, 
3 - Mysql databases -> Create a database, 
4 - Create a user, 
5 - Get the confirmation that db and user created and assigned properly, 
6 - Return to Cpanel home->Click phpmyadmin 
7 - The database does not show. Refresh ->nothing changes. 
8 - Return to CPanel->MySQL databases->the database exists there but phpmyadmin does not have it.
```

I searched the internet and tried all the relevant solution but no chance!
Thanks...

Comment: Does the user that you are logging onto _phpmyadmin_ with have permission on that database? If not, it will not even appear.

Comment: Yes, the user has all the privileges both on the DB and the phpmyadmin. I have tested different user options.

Comment: On the user that you are able to login to _phpmyadmin_ with, can you execute the statement `flush privileges` to force them to be reloaded?

Comment: @Matt: How do I execute flush privileges in CPanel?

Comment: I actually mean run it from within _phpmyadmin_.

Comment: Try execute on shell /scripts/update_db_cache   If not work try  /usr/local/cpanel/bin/setupdbmap

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Solved!
For the people who may see the same issue here how it was resolved:

```
1 - Create a new database by completing the CPanel`s wizard->check phpmyadmin, if it does not show up continue with step 2,
2 - Close phpmyadmin,
3 - Logout CPanel,
4 - Login to CPanel again
5 - Open phpmyadmin->the new database is there!
```

Comment: Almost 2019 and we're at this shit. I can't freaking believe it. It worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Why is this the case tho?

Answer (score 12):

If you have added a database and a user from MySQL, then simply log out from cPanel and log in again and you will get the database. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Once you created your database just logout from your Cpanel.
Then you can again login on Cpanel and go to phpmyadmin.
Your newly created database would be there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you created database in mysql database and not appear in phpmyadmin, log out from cPanel and log in again It will appear in phpmayadmin

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL® Databases`:
Select your database in `Modify Databases` section and click `Check Database` button.

[image]